# Issue Sending Post Data To PhP

Tags: php, c++, http-post

The Library Im Using: https://github.com/Code-Building/requests

PHP

````
if (register($_GET['username'], $_GET['password'], $_GET['hwid'])) { ... }
```
````

C++

```
    http::request* result = http::post("https://xxx/api/handle.php?t=", data);

    printf("%s", result->text.c_str());
```

I would like to add running this on a local server works just fine, having issues with livenet since thats what our teacher wants.
Also the issue is sending the post data. Manually entering post data / sending with fiddler work just fine. Any Ideas?

(Ive also used $_POST didnt work aswell)

Comment: POST request parameters should be in request body, not appended to URL like `?t=...`.

Comment: ***Manually entering post data / sending with fiddler work just fine*** please provide an example POST request.

Comment: I use t as a query string to know what part in handle.PHP to use. a is for the login and t is for the register

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GLL:AT530 to send the PHP request, or just use Tractor API, it's really good for sending data to PHP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).